# Rebuild MySQL indexed reporting table without downtime

Tags: mysql

I want to create a large denormalized table to run reports off of that completely rebuilds every ten minutes by a chron job. This would preferably be indexed as well. However, if I just make a stored procedure or something that truncates and re-inserts the table, there is going to be downtime for existing reports hitting the table.

What is a good way to do this so there is no downtime? I am thinking about building it into a second table and then swapping table names once it is ready, but don't know if this is a bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

There is a much better way to build "Reports" from a large dataset.

Build and maintain a "Summary Table" that provides subtotals for each day (or another useful time period).  Then build the Report from this table instead of the much bigger "Fact" table.  In my experience, a well designed Summary Table allows the Report to be generated in less than a second, thereby obviating the need for a corn job to regenerate -- simply generate it on demand.

If you provide more details, I can provide more specifics.  Meanwhile, study this:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables

It may be possible to provide up-to-the second reports instead of your current 10 minute delay.

The Summary table can be denormalized and have multiple indexes.  It also obviates the need for as many indexes on the Fact table.

For more discussion:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE
table size
The current SELECT that is run by corn
How 'current' the data should be
How frequently data is inserted in the Fact table.
```